# How to create a PEM file for storing an RSA key?

Tags: rsa, implementation, standards, file-format

I have an RSA private key $\{d,n\}$ and a public key $\{e,n\}$, where $n$ is the modulus, and I also have the prime factors $p$ and $q$ of $n$.

I want to create a PEM file containing this information, so that I can decrypt a file encrypted with the public key using OpenSSL.
How can I do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about how to use a particular software program (OpenSSL), not cryptography

Comment: @poncho: Technically, this question is about implementing a standard storage format for cryptographic keys. The mention of OpenSSL is really a red herring. I think it's on topic here, if perhaps marginally. (And there's certainly some overlap with [so] here; not that there's necessarily anything wrong with that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[RFC 2313](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2313.txt) specifies the `RSAPrivateKey` ASN1 structure as a `SEQUENCE` containing the `INTEGER`s

- $0$;
- $n$;
- $e$;
- $d$;
- $p$;
- $q$;
- $d\bmod(p-1)$;
- $d\bmod(q-1)$;
- $q^{-1}\bmod p$.

The PEM format consists of such a structure encoded as Base64 and framed by the typical `BEGIN/END RSA PRIVATE KEY` header and footer lines.

Thus, you can use any ASN1 library you like to encode the private key parameters. For example, with Python's `pyasn1` module, a private key file's contents can be obtained as follows:

```
import pyasn1.codec.der.encoder
import pyasn1.type.univ
import base64

def pempriv(n, e, d, p, q, dP, dQ, qInv):
    template = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n{}-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
    seq = pyasn1.type.univ.Sequence()
    for i,x in enumerate((0, n, e, d, p, q, dP, dQ, qInv)):
        seq.setComponentByPosition(i, pyasn1.type.univ.Integer(x))
    der = pyasn1.codec.der.encoder.encode(seq)
    return template.format(base64.encodebytes(der).decode('ascii'))
```

The parameters `dP`, `dQ` and `qInv` are most easily (as in: lines of code) computed as follows:

```
dP = d % (p-1)
dQ = d % (q-1)
qInv = pow(q, p-2, p)
```

Comment: `PyAsn1Error: Attempted "__len__" operation on ASN.1 schema object`

Comment: @evandrix Thanks, seems like some internals of `pyasn1` changed. Fixed.

Comment: python3 says: DeprecationWarning: encodestring() is a deprecated alias since 3.1, use encodebytes(). replacing it works fine as far as I can see.

Comment: the code given for `dP` and `dQ` is wrong. the one given for qInv is convoluted. consider this instead `expected_dP = d % (p - 1)`;`expected_dQ = d % (q - 1)`; `expected_qInv = pow(q, -1, p)`

Comment: @acapola Thanks! Fixed.